# Перемещение или перерисовка фигур на canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

Я разрабатываю приложение, где есть свечной график, который рисуется на основе binance api на canvas. Мне нужно сделать перемещение или перетаскивание графика с помощью зажатой мыши, как на traiding view, сам вопрос состоит в том, как лучше и быстрее перемещать график, я вижу три способа:

1. Рисовать фигуры, которые находятся за пределами canvas с отрицательной координатой и при перемещении просто перерисовывать и изменять координаты.
2. Использовать ofsscreen canvas.
3. Использовать drawImage().
4. Использовать метод setTransform() и фактически не перерисовывать.

Подскажите какой способ лучше или предложите свой.

Comment: способа три, а пункта 4. Не совсем понятно что ты имеешь ввиду под каждым пунктом

Comment: Извиняюсь, я имел в виду 4 способа.

Comment: добавь больше описания, в идеале с маленьким примером, для каждого пункта